# Specifying repository username while working with remote modules

Tags: git, github, terraform

I am trying to download a Terraform module using GitHub as source. The module source is given below:

```
  source = "github.com/my-org/tf-modules//azure/func-app/v1?ref=v2.0.0-major-1"
```

However, when I do `terraform init` I get the following error:

```
│ Could not download module "planner" (main.tf:15) source code from "github.com/myorg/tf-modules?ref=v2.0.0-major-1": error downloading
│ 'https://github.com/my-org/tf-modules.git?ref=v2.0.0-major-1': C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform\modules\planner'...
│ bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
│ error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
│ fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

Usually when I try to clone a repository using Git it prompts me to enter username and password (token) but here it's not asking and just exiting with a failure.

I can't use `ssh` as Git source so have to work with `https`, so how can a specify username for the module source and go around this error?

Answer (score 3):

Terraform doesn't support interactive prompts during module installation, including from Git, so to use a git source for a Terraform module will require you to specify the credentials in a different way, which will probably be one of the various options described in [the `gitcredentials` document](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

For the username in particular, you can configure Git to rewrite any URL it's given by matching a prefix and then replacing that prefix, using the `insteadOf` configuration setting in your Git configuration.

For example, the following will tell Git to insert the username "example" whenever it sees a URL that lacks a username on github.com:

```
[url "https://example@github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

This will only specify the username, though. You'll still need a separate solution for non-interactively supplying a password or auth token.

---

You mentioned that SSH is not appropriate in your situation, but for completeness (in case someone else finds this answer in future) I'll note that you can also use this technique to tell Git to use SSH instead of https:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

An advantage of using SSH, where it's available, is that it has a standard way to provide credentials non-interactively (using an authorized private key) and so it can neatly address both parts of the problem at once.

---

In both of these cases we can use Git configuration to neatly separate the general location of the repository shared across all users, specified as an `https:` URL with no particular credential information, from the details of how *one specific user* will connect to and authenticate to that repository.